# Twisted AMP Server connections pool

Tags: python, twisted

I have a TCP Server running over twisted, listening tcp clients. Also I have a Django App which send messages to the TCP Clients through an AMP on the Twisted Server.

Orders sent from the Djsngo App, wait for a AMP response, which wait for the TCP Client response.

My issue is about multiple orders sent, then AMP Server as deferred messages could cross messages on broke TCP client connections, then I need a way to manage this orders as a pool or other way on solve this charge connections

My AMP Server is

```
"""Amp Server """
from twisted.protocols.amp import AMP, Command, String

class AmpProcessor(Command):
    arguments = [('proto', String()),
                 ('imei', String()),
                 ('ip', String()),
                 ('port', String()),
                 ('cmmd', String()),
                 ('mssg', String())]
    response = [('answer', String())]

class AMPServer(AMP):

    @AmpProcessor.responder
    def processor(self, proto, imei, ip, port, cmmd, mssg):
        try:
            response = self.factories[proto].clients[ip].runCommand(cmmd, mssg)
            return {'answer': str(response)}
        except:
            return {'answer': str('FAIL')}
```

What my server do is, when I connection is received, params gotten are

- Proto: Index on hw TCP clients are been stored
- Imei: Client identificator
- Ip: Client connection IP
- Port: Port Connection
- Cmmd: Order, it is a method that will be executed
- Mssg: Message that will be sent to the client

Once teh connection is received the AMP check its array where clients connections are stored and use the instance in order to send the order

Then I am looking for manage connection, something like a pool for no crash client connections

**My TCP Server**

```
from twisted.internet import threads
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory, Protocol

class TrackerServer(Protocol):
    """Tracker Twisted Protocol Class."""

    def __init__(self, clients, devicer):
        self.clients = clients
        self.devicer = devicer
        self.decoder = None
        self.host = None
        self.peer = None
        self.state = False

    def connectionMade(self):
        """ConnectionMade Twisted event."""
        try:
            decoderModule = __import__('listener.protocols.%sDecoder' % (self.devicer, ), fromlist=['%sDecoder' % (self.devicer, )])
            decoderClass = getattr(decoderModule, '%sDecoder' % (self.devicer, ))
            self.decoder = decoderClass()
            self.peer = self.transport.getPeer()
            self.host = self.transport.getHost()
            self.decoder.openConnection(self.host.host, self.host.port, self.peer.host, self.peer.port)
            print 'Connection made to', self.host, 'from', self.peer
            self.clients[self.peer.host] =  self
        except ValueError:
            print "Oops!  Connection was not started"

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        """ConnectionLost Twisted event."""
        if self.clients.has_key(self.peer.host):
            del self.clients[self.peer.host]
            self.decoder.closeConnection()
            print "Connection lost from", self.peer.host, ':', reason
        else:
            print "Connection unknown peer:", reason

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        """DataReceived Twisted event."""
        #try:
        """ how to precess here a line for a specific client"""
        response = self.decoder.processDatagram(data)
        if  response != False:
            self.sendMessage(response)
            #d = threads.deferToThread(self.factory.decoder.processDatagram(data ))
            #d.addCallback(self.sendResponse)
        #except ValueError:
        #    print "Oops!  That was no valid data.  Try again..."

    def sendMessage (self, response):
        self.transport.write(response)

class TrackerFactory(Factory):

    def __init__(self, devicer):
        self.clients = {}
        self.devicer = devicer

    def buildProtocol(self, addr):
        proto = TrackerServer(self.clients, self.devicer)
        self.connectedProtocol = proto
        return proto
```

**My *.tac file**

```
import os, sys
import ConfigParser
from twisted.application import internet, service
from twisted.internet import protocol, reactor
from listener.TrackerServer import TrackerFactory
from listener.AMPServer import AMPServer
from twisted.internet.protocol import Factory
from twisted.internet.endpoints import TCP4ServerEndpoint
from twisted.application.internet import StreamServerEndpointService

PROJECT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR)

path = None
config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read('protocols.cfg')

application = service.Application("tracker")

factories = {}

for device in config.get('protocols', 'keys').split(','):
    devicer = config.get(device, 'name')
    factories[devicer] = TrackerFactory(devicer)
    internet.TCPServer(int(config.get(device, 'port')), factories[devicer]).setServiceParent(application)

endpoint = TCP4ServerEndpoint(reactor, 8750)
factory = Factory()
factory.protocol = AMPServer
factory.protocol.factories = factories
ampService = StreamServerEndpointService(endpoint, factory)
ampService.setServiceParent(application)
```

Comment: I really don't understand your question.  Your AMP server is not enough of a sample: what is your AMP client doing?  What do you *want* it to do?